# How to change Azure Data Factory Diagnostics Setting to "Resource specific" table using PowerShell

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory, I want to change the Diagnostic Settings to "Resource Specific" destination table using PowerShell. I have the existing settings which is sending logs to "Azure Diagnostics" tables. I want to change this default setting using PowerShell and to avoid the full diagnostic setting deployment again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the command below, in my sample, `joyfactory` is my datafactory name, `joyfactorydia` is the diagnosticSetting name, replace them and the `<subscription-id>` and `<group-name>` in the command.

Also make sure your `Az.Accounts` powershell module is not too old, at least has the new command [`Invoke-AzRestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/invoke-azrestmethod?view=azps-5.1.0), if it is old, you could use `Update-Module -Name Az.Accounts` to update it.

```
Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method PUT -Path "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<group-name>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/joyfactory/providers/microsoft.insights/diagnosticSettings/joyfactorydia?api-version=2017-05-01-preview" `
 -Payload '{
    "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<group-name>/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/joyfactory/providers/microsoft.insights/diagnosticSettings/joyfactorydia",
    "name": "joyfactorydia",
    "properties": {
        "logs": [{
            "category": "ActivityRuns",
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            }
        }, {
            "category": "PipelineRuns",
            "enabled": false,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            }
        }, {
            "category": "TriggerRuns",
            "enabled": false,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            }
        }, {
            "category": "SSISPackageEventMessages",
            "enabled": false,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            }
        }, {
            "category": "SSISPackageExecutableStatistics",
            "enabled": false,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            }
        }, {
            "category": "SSISPackageEventMessageContext",
            "enabled": false,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            }
        }, {
            "category": "SSISPackageExecutionComponentPhases",
            "enabled": false,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            }
        }, {
            "category": "SSISPackageExecutionDataStatistics",
            "enabled": false,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            }
        }, {
            "category": "SSISIntegrationRuntimeLogs",
            "enabled": false,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            }
        }],
        "metrics": [{
            "enabled": true,
            "retentionPolicy": {
                "days": 0,
                "enabled": false
            },
            "category": "AllMetrics"
        }],
        "workspaceId": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourcegroups/<group-name>/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/joylogana",
        "logAnalyticsDestinationType": "Dedicated"
    }
}'
```

[image]

[image]

In the `Payload` , `"logAnalyticsDestinationType": "Dedicated"` is what you want, it changes the `Destination table` to `Resource specific`. For other values, you could refer to the result of the commands below, then fix them using the format in the `Payload` above.

```
$id = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name joyfactory).DataFactoryId
Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name joyfactorydia -ResourceId $id
```

---

**Besides**, I have also tried `Set-AzDiagnosticSetting` and `Set-AzResource`, both not work, there are maybe some bugs, not write them in detail here.

If you can accept to use the Azure CLI, there is the easiest way:

```
$id = (Get-AzDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name joyfactory).DataFactoryId
$dia = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name joyfactorydia -ResourceId $id 
az resource update --ids $dia.Id --api-version '2017-05-01-preview' --set properties.logAnalyticsDestinationType=Dedicated
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Joy. I think both REST method and az cli commands should work. Will try it and mark it as answer.